# Known Windows vulnerabilities vs actual exploits on Microsoft's websites?

Tags: server, defense, vulnerability

Although some of Microsoft's servers are running on Linux, at least half is running Windows Server of some kind.
I'm trying to understand how with so many unpatched and unresolved vulnerabilities in Windows Microsoft's websites remain operational and don't get defaced on a regular basis or even on any basis at all. Is Windows (server) really that secure so we need not even install any patches or is there a trick to it that Microsoft employs?

Comment: Not all vulnerabilities are exploitable over a remote connection.

Comment: Are you seriously claiming that Microsoft doesn't install the publicly available set of security patches on its own servers?  Then why are you trying to infer "that secure so we need not even install any patches"?  What the data supports is "You should install the same patches Microsoft does."

Comment: They do. I was thinking of zero-day exploits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the servers runing win server are in separated network and you access them through linux servers. On these servers is performed filtration of requests so can not use some exploits or known security holes because your attempts even not reach your victim servers.

Comment: Yeah, actually that sounds plausible. Now that you mentioned it I think I vaguely remember something similar being said a long time ago.